# Is there a Vanilla Twitter Bootstrap 3 Wordpress theme that works well with CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, theme

I'm taking an existing static website that was created with Twitter Bootstrap 3 with no modifications to the framework and trying to shoehorn it into Wordpress with CiviCRM.

Makes use of the following examples from the bootstrap-3.0.3 code base:

- navbar-fixed-top (all pages)
- carousel
- offcanvas
- jumbo-tron
- grid

I found the [following theme](http://bragthemes.com/theme/builder-bootstrap-3-starter-theme/) for $38 dollars, but it seems a little lacking in features.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you mean by "Works well with Civicrm"

Comment: Can we move it to the wordpress SE?